# Delete Google Drive files automatically/ quickly without browser?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

As per this post, I also need a script to delete google drive files.

I am new to using the google drive realtime API, and have probably created and saved hundreds of realtime files to my drive during my testing. Now if I go to drive in the standard way through the browser, it doesn't load (40 minutes and counting); that's how clogged up it is.

The files were created with this code: (using the Google Drive API)

```
createRealtimeFile: function(title, callback) {
var that = this;
window.gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function() {
  var insertHash = {
    'resource': {
      mimeType: that.mimeType,
      title: title
    }
  };
  window.gapi.client.drive.files.insert(insertHash).execute(callback);
});
},
```

They are saved, I'm assuming, to https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/FILE_ID where FILEID is a collection of characters such as this - "0B6sZ2SWZ13-QZlNuRlBXQ1NUWjA"

However, I only want to delete the files I created yesterday (July 9, 2015 up to 1am, July 10, 2015), so as to not delete all of my drive! Is there a way to do this?

Well, I can't use my browser, so it'll have to be a script or through the terminal. And hopefully in a fast/automated fashion. I would be so grateful!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it in Drive API, only on GAS, and since you can't access the files, and probably can't create a Script File, here's a script I created and shared. The code in it (also below, in case anyone deletes it) logs the name of all files that are created till 24 hours after July the 9th:

https://script.google.com/macros/d/1q8oLJrh6ZbiFjiSy1L9_xfyfwiTQ_1AcB406VQ6dt8rPa3tWi8k8dadN/edit?template=default&folder=0AMUlP1OgiWTXUk9PVA&usp=drive_web

```
function deleteRecentFiles() {
  var oldestDate = new Date(2015, 6, 9),
      newestDate = new Date(2015, 6, 10),
      filesRoot = DriveApp.getFiles(),
      currFile, dateFileCreated;
  while(filesRoot.hasNext){
    currFile = filesRoot.next();
    dateFileCreated = currFile.getDateCreated();
    if( dateFileCreated > oldestDate && dateFileCreated < newestDate ){
      Logger.log(currFile.getName());
      // Uncomment to send file to trash bin
      //currFile.setTrashed(true);
    }
  }
}
```

It probably won't be able to delete all files in the first run, after it timeouts (6 minutes), run again after 6 minutes untill all files are deleted.